# App is not shown in Alarms & Reminders besides setting the SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission in manifest

Tags: android, permissions, alarm

As the title says, I have an app that targets Android 12 with `compileSdkVersion = 31` and should trigger an exact alarm. The issue here is that the app is given the `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` permission in the manifest but it isn't shown in `Alarms & Reminders` list.

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />

<application
  ...
    <receiver
        android:name=".boot.AlarmReceiver"
        android:exported="false"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM_PERMISSION_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
 ...
</application>
```

I've tried debugging it using `ACTION_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM_PERMISSION_STATE_CHANGED` in the broadcast receiver which also includes intent filter and the intent action to check whether if listens to that change and forcefully changing the `REQUIRE_EXACT_ALARM_PERMISSION` permission through `App Compatibility Changes` in Developer settings which it works.

```
    private fun runOnBootCompleted(intentAction: String) {
    if (intentAction == AlarmManager.ACTION_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM_PERMISSION_STATE_CHANGED
    ) {                
     alarmManager.setRepeatingAlarm()
    }
}
```

Before setting the alarm I am checking whether the permission for it has been granted

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S &&!alarmManager.canScheduleExactAlarms()) {
                    openAlarmSettings()
                } else {
                    setRepeatingAlarm()
                }
```

This works perfectly, even when turning off the `REQUIRE_EXACT_ALARM_PERMISSION` it behaves as it should.

Is there something that I am missing which should be required for the app to be shown in the `Alarms & Reminders` list?

Comment: have you find any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set -

```
    androidCompileSdkVersion = 31
    androidTargetSdkVersion = 31
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings and check the App battery usage part of your app. If your app uses the battery optimization mode of Unrestricted (Don't optimize battery usage) the application will not be shown in the list of Alarms & Reminders.